# Naming conventions for `d3.select(this.el)` in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, naming-conventions, d3.js

Inside a `Backbone.View` `this.el` normally refers to the node element that the view is based 
on, and `this.$el` refers to the jquery version `$(this.el)`.

I'm using Backbone with the d3 library and was wondering if there was a standard naming convention for the d3 version `d3.select(this.el)`? Perhaps `this.d3el`?

Comment: In coffeescript with `@el` and `@$el` such a convention would be percentage wise even more helpful.

Comment: My strong suspicion is that not enough people have a) used these libraries together and b) thought to cache the D3 selection to actually have produced any conventions around this. Use whatever works for you :).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `d3` defined as `window.d3`? Therefore, it's available globally so there shouldn't be a need to scope it within the view. Unless I'm missing something here!

Comment: I'm not talking about the d3 library, but the d3 selection of the view element